# Why IDataSource Interface exists for ASP.NET and not for Winform?

Tags: c#

I have looked at BindingSource class in winform and the datasource member type is Object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource.aspx).

Wouldn't it be a better design if datasource was of IDataSource Class Interface like it seems in ASP.NET ?

Answer (score 1):

Having a property of type object allows you to set anything as a data source. Then, the `BindingSource` is responsible of the transformation. It's only a convenience matter.

From the page you link in you question, if you set to the property:

- a null reference, the data source will be an empty `IBindingList` of objects. Adding an item sets the list to the type of the added item.
- a non-list type or object of type "T", you'll get an empty `IBindingList` of type "T".
- an array instance, and it will be a `IBindingList` containing the array elements.
- an `IEnumerable` instance will be transformed into an `IBindingList` containing the `IEnumerable` items.
- a List instance containing type "T", and the data source will be an `IBindingList` instance containing type "T".

It seems less safe, since it's not strongly typed, but it appears to be pretty handy.

Comment: Yes no typing is handy but why did they type for ASP.NET and not for Winform is it because Winform is neglected ?

Comment: Well, first, no typing is rarely handy if you ask me. Then, I can only guess why APIs are differents, and I think that's only because very different teams were in charge of ASP.NET and Winforms. On a large framework like .NET, that's the type of inconsistencies you can punctually encounter. But maybe there is a more formal reason.